# Does Python/Django guarantee that the objects from foreign key will stay in the same order?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Case:
   case_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SubTask:
   subtask_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Suppose I create four objects of SubTask *st1*,*st2*,*st3*, and *st4* **in this order** and set their case attribute to the Case instance *C*. Now my question is, when I do this loop:

```
for subtask in SubTask.objects.filter(case=C):
  #Do something to subtasks
```

Is it **guaranteed** by python or Django that the objects in this loop will appear in the order st1,st2,st3, then st4? Or does it only guarantee that the four objects will be looped over in any order?

Note: I did try it and they were in the order of instantiation, However, I want to make sure that this behavior is guaranteed since the ordering matters.

Answer (score 4):

Django does not impose any order, except for any that you supply yourself. If your SubTask model has an `ordering` attribute in its Meta class, then subtasks will always be ordered in that way; or, you can supply an `order_by` clause explicitly when filtering.

Otherwise, Django just provides the items in the order that the database supplies them. Note that while dbs may well return things in the order you want, strictly speaking order in SQL is undefined if not explicitly stated.

Comment: Is there any built in way to make this ordering using order_by(???), or do I have to add a 'created_at' attribute to the model and set it to timezone.now() when the object is created?

Comment: The only way to guarantee insertion order is to add a timestamp field, yes. Note that Django will set the creation date automatically if you use `auto_now_add=True` in the definition.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the primary key to make sure that the objects are iterated over in the same order as they are added to database.

```
for subtask in SubTask.objects.filter(case=C).order_by('pk'):
  #Do something to subtasks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ordering` option in the `Case` `Meta` class. See the documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#ordering